# SwiftUI Path .closeSubpath() not working the same way as UIBezierPath .close()

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to draw the following shape with SwiftUI:

[image: Price tag shape]

Before SwiftUI I just had to create a UIBezierPath, add the corners with addArc and then finally call close(), but I don't get the same result when calling closeSubpath on SwiftUI Path.

Here's my code:

```
            Path { path in
                let width: CGFloat = 23
                let height: CGFloat = 24
                let arrowWidth = height / 2.0
                let cornerRadius = height / 7.5

                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: width - cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), endAngle: .zero, clockwise: true)
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height - cornerRadius))
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: width - cornerRadius, y: height - cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: .zero, endAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), clockwise: true)
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: arrowWidth + cornerRadius, y: height - cornerRadius), radius:  cornerRadius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 135), clockwise: true)
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: height / 2.0), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 135), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 225), clockwise: true)
                path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: arrowWidth + cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 225), endAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), clockwise: true)
                path.closeSubpath()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you see?  I get your nice shape if I change every `clockwise: true` to `clockwise: false`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be drawn via `Shape`, which specifies rect for path, as in demo below

*Note: also fixed clockwise direction*

[image: demo]

```
struct NewShape_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewShape()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 48)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }
}

struct NewShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            let width: CGFloat = rect.width
            let height: CGFloat = rect.height
            let arrowWidth = height / 2.0
            let cornerRadius = height / 7.5

            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: width - cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), endAngle: .zero, clockwise: false)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height - cornerRadius))
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: width - cornerRadius, y: height - cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: .zero, endAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), clockwise: false)
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: arrowWidth + cornerRadius, y: height - cornerRadius), radius:  cornerRadius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 90), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 135), clockwise: false)
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: height / 2.0), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 135), endAngle: Angle(degrees: 225), clockwise: false)
            path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: arrowWidth + cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: Angle(degrees: 225), endAngle: Angle(degrees: -90), clockwise: false)
        }
    }
}
```