# CGPath in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, cgpath

While using `SwiftUI`, I am puzzled by this line of code:

```
xPath = Path(myPath.cgPath)
```

Here a broader context:

```
struct MyShape: Shape {
    @Binding var xPath:Path
    ........


    var myPath = Path()
    myPath.move(to: somePoint1)
    myPath.addLine(to: somePoint2)
    myPath.addLine(to: somePoint3)
    myPath.addLine(to: somePoint1)

    xPath = Path(myPath.cgPath)
```

Right after executing the line, here is what I get in the debugger console:

```
(lldb) p myPath
(Path) $R14 = {
  storage = path (path = 0x0000000280e081c0)
}
(lldb) p myPath.cgPath
(NSObject) $R16 = 0x000000028298cfc0 {
  baseNSObject@0 = {
    isa = __NSCFType
  }
}
(lldb) p myPath.description
(String) $R18 = "39.3916 34.8342 m 51.5 0 l 63.6084 34.8342 l 39.3916 34.8342 l"
(lldb) p xPath
(Path) $R20 = {
  storage = empty
}
```

Does this seem OK? Since myPath contains something, I find it strange that xPath looks like it is empty at the end.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `myPath` is a reference, `xPath` is a value. If anything wrong in behaviour please show the code.

Comment: @Asperi; I updated the post, hoping more context will be useful.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to accomplish, but if just to create custom shape, then look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60564856/12299030), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61537449/12299030), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61345344/12299030) examples, or just search by keywords.

Comment: @Asperi; OK. I may need to explain. The "creating a custom shape" part of the game is already working perfectly. The variable xPath is something (else) aside that I want to set with the code in my post (doing it while I create the shape just happens to be convenient). But I must be doing something wrong when passing the binding for xPath.

Comment: But in any case my question is still valid. Does it seem normal that xPath is empty at this point of the code?